# Filter clinical trials based on start date using Python package

Tags: python, package

I am using the `clinical trials package` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clinical_trials/1.1) to fetch data about clinical trials. I would like to restrict the results to those after a certain year (say, 2014). How does one apply such a filter?

```
results = trials.search(queryString, condition = 'Myeloma', start_date = '>2014',count=500)
```

runs but doesn't restrict the results based on `start_date`. The start date typically has a `Month YYYY` format

Comment: What does the documentation for `trials.search` say?

Comment: Nothing. The link above is all the documentation there is.

Comment: Does a start date of `'2015'` work?